# AMP Story javascript library return 404 Not Found

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to use the amp story by including

https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-story-1.0.js in the header as instructed in github, but I found out that library doesn't exist at that URL.

Comment: visit this link: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-story#children-of-amp-story-grid-layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/14695) in the documentation; you should instead use `https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-story-0.1.js`.